# Are SKSearchResults distinct without the parentIndex?

Tags: android, skmaps

Is a SKSearchResult like the below one distinct **without** the parent ID?

```
SKSearchResult [id=89926544, type=STREET, name=Grüne Aue, 
parentsList=[SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1623511944, parentType=CITY_SECTOR, parentName=Anderten], 
    SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1623511944, parentType=CITY, parentName=Hannover], 
    SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1623511944, parentType=STATE, parentName=Niedersachsen], 
    SKSearchResultParent [parentIndex=1623511944, parentType=COUNTRY, parentName=Deutschland]], 
    category=SKPOI_CATEGORY_UNKNOWN, mainCategory=null, location=[9.848663330078125,52.36086654663086], offlinePackageCode=DE
```

So can I expect the same SKSearchResult, if I search for that?:

- Deutschland
- Niedersachsen
- Hannover
- Anderten
- Grüne Aue

Or do I have to store all `parentIndex`-values to repeat a search with the same result?

Comment: Question routed to search developers